# Excel. How to shift date in one cell when the date in another cell is changed?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say Column A contains start dates e.g. cell A2 = 1-Jun-22 etc, and Column B contains end dates e.g. cell B2 = 1-Jul-22.

Now say I change the start date to any time earlier, e.g. 1 month earlier so 1-May-22.

How can I make it so that the end date is automatically shifted forward the same amount of days (in this case one month) as well?

Comment: MAke B2 dependant on A2 with a formula. IT depends if you are working on days, complete months ot what. In your example. A2 = 1-Jun_22 and B2 would be `=EDATE(A2,1)` [EDATE Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edate-function-3c920eb2-6e66-44e7-a1f5-753ae47ee4f5)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.